# Storing application runtime properties in a database

Tags: database, properties, jakarta-ee

Is it a good idea? I've never seen it done before.

The application in question is an enterprise project deployed as an EAR file on an app server. Properties include path to log file, name of JMS topic, etc. The intention being properties can be queried at runtime from the database, rather than having to redeploy the entire application, which might cause downtime and require developer/administrator attention.

How else would I modify runtime properties of the enterprise application?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you intending to ask whether a database or flat config file is a better solution, or...?

Comment: I'm asking whether it's a good idea to have a table in a database storing purely runtime properties. A flat config file can't be modified if it's packaged with the EAR file.

Comment: Yes it can inside the ear or even with a re-deploy but generally it can even be written in another location other than inside the ear and the app reads it in run-time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that or you can use properties file (config file) to store such info as I have seen this done on multiple projects. The preference of choosing between database and properties file is dependent on many factors but assuming the data are too little to be on database table, it's really fine for both solutions.